# how do I write an ISO file to disk under Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: burning

I downloaded Windows 7 Home Premium and want to burn the ISO image to DVD. I right click on the ISO file but "Write to Disk" does not come up.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

What do I do, please?

Comment: Install "Brasero". See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

Comment: @Jos can you move your comment to an answer please.

Answer (score 10):

As of 16.04, a CD/DVD burning application is no longer installed by default. You will need to do so yourself.

Find [Brasero](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Brasero) in the software center (or enter `sudo apt install brasero` in a terminal). For a longer explanation with screenshots, see the DVD burning guide for 16.04 [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu).

Comment: My mistake. I totally misread the question, so I've deleted all of my comments. This is a good answer.. My apologies to you.